# ArcMap Time enabled raster catalog greyed out raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, animation, timeslider, raster-catalog

I am having a problem trying to make an animation from a raster catalog.

In the past, I have:

1. Added the raster catalogue to ArcMap
2. Added a new date field
3. Enabled time on the catalogue later
4. Created the animation and exported

For some reason with one particular raster catalogue, when I create the animation, I get a grey box through the entire series. Each of the individual rasters has the correct information, but for some reason when the animated frames are greyed out.

Is there something I missed?

I below is a screen grab of a random raster that shows up greyed out in the animation, but definitely has data in the Raster Viewer.

[image]